# Semantics of `let` assignment in Nim

Tags: variable-assignment, semantics, assign, let, nim-lang

## Semantics of `let` assignment in Nim

I was recommended the Nim programming language and started reading through the [Tutorial 1](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html), the [Manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html) and even the [memory model](http://zevv.nl/nim-memory/) (in particular the section about [strings and seqs](http://zevv.nl/nim-memory/#_strings_and_seqs)).

I soon encountered some strange behavior regarding `let` assignment which doesn't seem to make any sense at all, to the point of appearing a complete mess. I can demonstrate all the nonsense with this simple script ([link to playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=4B2x)):

```
echo "first example:"

proc p =
  var msg = "Hello"
  let copy = msg
  msg.add(" World!")
  echo msg
  echo copy # does NOT change
p()

echo "\nsecond example:"

proc q =
  var msg = "Hello"
  let copy = msg
  msg.add("!")
  echo msg
  echo copy # DOES change
q()

echo "\nthird example:"

var msg = "Hello"
let copy = msg
msg.add("!")
echo msg
echo copy # does NOT change
```

In the first and third examples, `copy` retains the original value `"Hello"`. The second example (`proc q`) shares a similarity with the other two cases:

- it is similar to the first because it employs the local scope of a `proc`,
- it is similar to the third because it appends the same string (`"!"`).

For some arcane reason however, in the first and third examples `copy` is indeed a copy (bind by value?), whereas in the second example the modification to the variable `msg` propagates to the immutable `copy` (bind by reference?).

What is going on? How can we make sense of this? **Does `let` bind by value or by reference?** If it make sense somehow, why is it not explained *clearly and in depth* in the official guides?

Comment: This is quite likely related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73940369/nim-sequence-assignment-value-semantics

Comment: @StefanZobel Oh my God you are right, IT IS A MESS indeed... Ok, I will immediately steer clear of a language that hasn't even made up its mind about the exact rules of binding identifiers

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you append and the resulting string is less than 8 bytes. I. e. if you append to `var msg="1"` less than 7 chars, the copied `let copy = msg` also gets modified. Appending 7 or more and the two strings are different:

```
proc q =
  var original = "1"
  let copy = original
  original.add "2"
  echo original, " ", copy

q()

>>> 12 12
```

The `addr` of both are the same:

```
  echo original.repr, " ", copy.repr

>>> 0x7fa5ac992060"12" 0x7fa5ac992060"12"
```

But if you add characters enough that the final `original` string gets to 8 bits or more:

```
proc q =
  var original = "1"
  let copy = original
  original.add "234567"

  echo original, " ", copy
  echo original.repr, " ", copy.repr

  original.add "8"

  echo original, " ", copy
  echo original.repr, " ", copy.repr

q()

>>> 1234567 1234567
>>> 0x7f2f0f5cb060"1234567" 0x7f2f0f5cb060"1234567"
>>> 12345678 1234567
>>> 0x7f2f0f5cb1b0"12345678" 0x7f2f0f5cb060"1234567"
```

The `original` string gets a new address, and the `copy` is still at the initial one.

Comment: Yeah, so this actually confirms that the semantics of the language is a complete mess

Comment: It looks like a bug, not an irreversible semantics problem. Similar problems were reported and fixed before. Also "complete mess" is a little exageration, given this code is a bit unrealistic. Wouldn't be a surprise if this is a side effect of a C compiler optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I found strange thing:

```
msg.add("!") # work in procedures (1 and 2 examples, but not 3)
```

```
msg.add(" World!") # doesn't work in all examples
```

At top-level string variable just copied, but in procedures small changes looks like changing pointers, but big changes looks like copy ...

I'm trying to change `let` to `var` and here is not changes.

I think that reason is compiler bug.

Comment: I found that in the `q` proc if you add either "!" or "!!" it binds by reference and the original gets also modified. But if you add "!!!", it doesn't modify the original.

Comment: Exactly, it's a nightmare...